# How could I add extra information to my simple html dom query

Tags: javascript, php, json, dom, simple-html-dom

I have a daily updated source (**this is not the fixtures.php what you find in my code, this is very important!**) about football informations. I would like to add some data to my existing simple html dom query.

The sample of the data source:

```
var info = new Array(); 
info[0] = new Array('','England','','League One','BARNSLEY',35,4.9,23.6,67,181,'',36,'CHESTERFIELD',2.8,25.3,11,184,'',36,22,'','',28,2,4,0,4,3,3,1,4,3,4,2,0,7,2,3,3,2,2,0,0,3,0,1,3,1,3,3,5,2,5,' 11','6 ',55,25,25,30,30,30,4,2,1,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2); info[1] = new Array('','Austria','','Bundesliga','WIENER NEUSTADT',213,6.0,25.2,34,181,'',30,'RIED',8.9,24.0,38,182,'',42,28,'','',28,3,0,2,1,2,0,4,4,0,3,2,1,4,3,5,2,0,3,0,2,3,0,3,0,3,1,3,5,2,5,' 9','6 ',30,30,30,30,30,35,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,1,2,2);info[2] = new Array('','England','','League One','DONCASTER',273,5.6,26.6,50,181,'',41,'ROCHDALE',3.4,25.3,23,182,'',31,27,'','',28,4,2,3,2,0,4,3,0,4,0,1,0,5,2,5,2,4,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,3,0,1,3,2,7,' 12','7 ',35,30,25,35,30,30,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2); info[3] = new Array('','England','','League One','GILLINGHAM',342,2.4,24.3,32,182,'',33,'BRADFORD',6.1,27.1,41,181,'',39,27,'','',28,3,1,0,0,4,3,4,4,1,2,2,1,5,2,5,4,2,1,4,2,4,1,0,2,2,0,4,4,4,4,' 14','9 ',30,30,35,30,30,30,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1);
```

My existing simple html dom query (which use an another php source which contains a simple html dom table with football fixtures).

```
<?php

include ("mysql.php");
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $html = file_get_html('fixtures.php');

class fixtures {
    var $matchday;
    var $kickofftime;
    var $hometeam;
    var $awayteam;


    function fixtures ($matchday, $kickofftime, $hometeam, $awayteam){
                $this->matchday=$matchday;
                $this->kickofftime=$kickofftime;
                $this->hometeam=$hometeam;
                $this->awayteam=$awayteam;
        return $this;
    }
}

$i=0;

$matchday=$html->find('h1',0);
$matchday->plaintext;

foreach($html->find('table.fixtures') as $fixtures) 
{




    foreach ($fixtures->find('tr[class=white],tr[class=grey]') as $fixturesTR) {

$kickofftime=$fixturesTR->find('td[class=a1],td[class=a2]',0)->plaintext;
$hometeam=$fixturesTR->find('td[class=ht]')->plaintext;
$awayteam=$fixturesTR->find('td[class=at]')->plaintext;

$i++;

echo $kickofftime;
echo $hometeam;
echo $awayteam;


    }
        }

?>
```

My question: How can I update my existing simple html dom query? (**I would like to use the two source together, this is very important**).

My current result with my existing simple html dom query:

```
1988-12-11 18:00 Barnsley Chesterfield 
1988-12-13 16:00 Wiener Neustadt Ried
1988-12-12 20:15 Doncaster Rochdale
1988-12-12 21:15 Gillingham Bradford
```

.
..
...

I would like this result:

```
1988-12-11 18:00 Barnsley 11 181 Chesterfield 6 184 England League One 35
1988-12-13 16:00 Wiener Neustadt 9 181 Ried 6 182 Austria Bundesliga 213
1988-12-12 20:15 Doncaster 12 181 Rochdale 7 182 England League One 273
1988-12-12 21:15 Gillingham 14 182 Bradford 9 181 England League One 342
```

Thanks. (Excuse me for I asked again, but it is very important).

Comment: If you want to get the answer, clear what you can't to do with simplehtmldom. I read second time your question and don't understand what is that digits and fromwhere they are

Comment: I would like to use this digits from the array what you view at my sample of my data source. This data source is not same as my source to simple html dom, it is a simple football fixtures website. I would like to add team positions, avg height (like Barnsley 11 181 and Chesterfield 6 184) plus the distance between the two clubs (35).  You can find these data at the sample of my data source.